# Classifer for unbalanced dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, unbalanced-classes, computer-vision

Is there any classifer that can natively support unbalanced datasets?
Or what best practices you can suggest to handle such datasets?

For example I want to solve task called "pedestrian detection" [classical approach](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) use linear SVM, but it can't handle unbalanced dataset (lots of background examples, small number of positive examples - people).Maybe there is something better than SVM? (I already know about undersampling/oversampling and weighted SVM).

It would be great if in answer you link to some scikit-learn classification algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Most classifiers in `sklearn` support unbalanced datasets, through the `sample_weight` parameter in the `clf.fit` methods.  If you need to fit unbalanced data with a classifier that does not support this option, you can use sampling with replacement to enlarge the smaller class to match the larger one.

Here is an adapted version of [the `sklearn` SVM example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html) demonstrating the `sample_weight` approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import svm

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.r_[2*np.random.randn(20, 2) - [2, 2], 2*np.random.randn(200, 2) + [2, 2]]
Y = [0] * 20 + [1] * 200
wt = [1/20.]*20 + [1/200.]*200

# fit the model
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, Y, sample_weight=wt)
```

[This question about unbalanced classification using `RandomForestClassifier`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082674/unbalanced-classification-using-randomforestclassifier-in-sklearn) has some additional details.

Comment: `sample_weight` is for particular data points, has nothing to do with unbalanced dataset. `class_weight` is the one.

Answer (score 2):

Linear SVM can handle unbalanced data sets just fine by using class-weights on the misclassification penalty. This functionality is available in any decent SVM implementation.

The objective function for class-weighted SVM is as follows:

$$\min_{\xi,\mathbf{w}} \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{w}\|^2 + C_{\mathcal{P}}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{P}} xi_i + C_\mathcal{N} \sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}} \xi_i, $$

where the minority class uses a higher misclassification penalty. A common heuristic is as follows:
$$C_\mathcal{P} \times |\mathcal{P}| = C_\mathcal{N} \times |\mathcal{N}|,$$
with $|\mathcal{P}|$ and $\mathcal{N}|$ the number of positive and negative training samples, respectively.

Comment: Why not just use a bias term (aka intercept from GLMs)?

Comment: @purple51 changing the intercept implies translating the separating hyperplane, which is not necessarily optimal. Modifying misclassification costs between classes also enables rotating the separating hyperplane, if necessary.

Comment: Right, although I suspect that optimizing the class weights is likely to lead to more severe overfitting than a simple intercept, especially when there's a small number of positives to begin with.